# Creación de una lista de objetos (cartas) a partir de valores aleatorios sin que se repitan dichos valores en C#

Tags: c#

```
  **for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
  x=Random.Range(1,51);
  if(!deck.Contains(x)){
  deck.Add(x);
  }
  deck[i] = CardDataBase.cardList[x];**
```

Para explicarles un poco, ando haciendo un juego de cartas en Unity porque me lo orientaron como proyecto y estoy trabajando con listas de  cartas, pero no sé cómo hacer para que a la hora de formar mi mazo obtenga cartas distintas de manera aleatoria y no las mismas

Comment: Queres ordenar el mazo de forma aleatoria? Si podes aclarar un poco el problema...

Comment: Creo que el concepto y la pregunta. Aqui deberias ir por generar el mazo de cartas primeramente en una lista y luego "desordenarla" (que es lo mismo que decir ordenar "aleatoriamente"). Y asi tomar lo que necesites de dicho listado. Pero intenta generar un codigo que te podamosa ayudar "puntualmente" en algo que tu lo hayas intentando y no presentando un problema general. Dale una mirada a [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)... busca, investiga, prueba...